# Dynamic virtual hosts in Apache

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost

I know it's possible to setup this system using a code of code, and a lot of pain-in-the-butt to maintain virtual hosts, but is there a dynamic way where it checks to be sure the folders exist?

I'd like to setup a system where on a site the default URL would be `www.domain.com` and it would look for `public_html/live/`, but if I set `dev.domain.com` it would look to `public_html/dev/`, BUT if I setup `dev-live.domain.com` it would look for `public_html/dev/` and it would use the LIVE database.

I'd like it to be setup so I only have to create a new directory within `public_html` in order to create a new subdomain, but still be able to maintain the ability to add `-[INSERT_DB]`

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use [mod_vhost_alias](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_vhost_alias.html) to get the arbitrary virtual hosts working with something like this:

```
UseCanonicalName Off
VirtualDocumentRoot /home/username/public_html/%1
```

I'm not sure how you intend on getting Apache to select the database, but you might be able to do that with [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html) and setting [DocumentRoot](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/mass.html#overview).

Answer (score 0):

Create a new virtualhost for your dev site. Something like:

```
<VirtualHost *>
        ServerName dev.domain.com
        ServerAlias dev*.domain.com    
        DocumentRoot /my/path/public_html/dev/
</VirtualHost>
```

That will route both dev.domain.com and dev-live.domain.com to the same place.

Since you also want to switch the databases dynamically, you will also need to change your application code to be smart enough to look at the incoming URL and use the correct database. You probably don't want to do that at the Apache level (just my opinion).

Comment: With this setup I would still need to have an entry for each repository, is there a way for me to make even this part dynamic, so that whatever I put in "dev" it'll look for that repo, if it's not found, it'll split by - and search for the first part of the split to see if that repo exists?